# Material-UI for java application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, reactjs, spring-boot, material-ui

I want to know if it's possible to use Material-UI within a java application ?

I'm currently using bootstrap and Spring forms for the frontend.  The backend is Spring MVC.

I would like to use React for the frontend (desktop and mobile).

In the Material-UI's documentation, it wrote that we need npm.

There is a way to use it for Spring boot ?

Does the tutorial : https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

is the way to go ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, please follow the step in https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/.
And then, if you want use Material-UI, you can just update **package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@material-ui/core": "latest"
```

}

And then, import material-ui in related .js
EG:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Material-UI with a java application. All the elements in Material-UI are **React Components**. Since you can show React Components on your page, you can show Material-UI element as well.